# Why PyCharm asks me to "Add global statement", when I assigned variable locally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I wrote this script for illustration purposes only, because I'm getting the same "Context Action" suggestion from PyCharm elsewhere in a larger script (script running fine).

```
dog = "Hungry"
def animal(status):
    while True:
        if status == "Hungry":
            action = "Feed Me"
        print(action)  # Right here it's highlighting "action" and asking me to add global statement
animal(dog)
```

Am I not assigning the variable "action" locally within my function "animal()"; and therefore I can freely use it anywhere else within the same function? Can someone explain why it's suggesting to make it a global variable?

Thank you!!!

Comment: What would happen if `status` was not `"Hungry"` in your current code?

Comment: PyCharm should *also* say "Local variable 'action' might be referenced before assignment ".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: @DavidG I see what you're trying to say, the print would result in an error. However, my actual code was set in a way such that the "while" and "if" statements had the same conditions, so it would've never printed unless both conditions were met. But you made it clear for me now, thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only setting `action` in the function scope if `status == "Hungry"`, but if `status != "Hungry"`, `action` is not set in the *local* scope. Now I can't really tell because you only posted part of you code, but I bet you have a variable named `action` in the outside scope - PyCharm thinks you want to access that, and therefore wants a `global` statement.
If you do not want to mix the local and outer `action`, just set it to something else in a `else` clause:

```py
dog = "Hungry"
def animal(status):
    while True:
        if status == "Hungry":
            action = "Feed Me"
        else:
            action = ""  # just set action to something to make sure it exists either way
        print(action)
animal(dog)
```